# How do I open Chrome on top of all programs via PowerShell?

Tags: windows, powershell

This code makes your program (always on top), which is what I'm trying to achieve with `Chrome`

Well, this code has been working fine for `Telegram`

```
$User32 = Add-Type -Debug:$False -MemberDefinition '[DllImport("user32.dll")] public static extern bool SetWindowPos(IntPtr hWnd, IntPtr hWndInsertAfter, int X,int Y, int cx, int cy, uint uFlags);' -Name "User32Functions" -namespace User32Functions -PassThru ; $Handle = (Get-Process -Name 'telegram').MainWindowHandle;[Void]$User32::SetWindowPos($Handle, -1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0x53)
```

But when I changed the name of the app from `telegram` to `chrome`, this error appears

```
Cannot convert argument "hWnd", with value: "System.Object[]", for "SetWindowPos" to type "System.IntPtr": "Cannot convert the
"System.Object[]" value of type "System.Object[]" to type "System.IntPtr"."
At line:1 char:318
+ ... indowHandle;[Void]$User32::SetWindowPos($Handle, -1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0x53 ...
+                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MethodArgumentConversionInvalidCastArgument
```

Do any of you have a solution or alternative to this?

Comment: That's because `Get-Process -Name chrome` returns _multiple processes_ - you need to pick 1, eg. `Get-Process -Name chrome |Where-Object { $_.MainWindowTitle } |Select -First 1`

Answer (score 1):

Chrome/Chromium uses a [multi-process architecture](https://www.chromium.org/developers/design-documents/multi-process-architecture/) to isolate rendering components for different tabs from each other. This means that a statement like `Get-Process chrome` will always return *multiple processes*.

To find one that owns the window you're interested in bringing to the foreground, inspect the `MainWindowTitle` of each process:

```
# fetch all `chrome` processes with at least one char in the window title
$windowOwningChromeProcesses = Get-Process chrome |Where-Object MainWindowTitle -like *?
```

That's not enough though - what if there are multiple windows open?

The safest option here is to sort for the window title you're expecting, then picking the best result:

```
$targetProcess = $windowOwningChromeProcesses |Sort-Object { $_.MainWindowTitle -match 'targetAppName' } |Select-Object -First 1
```

Now that you have at most one process handle to pass, PowerShell will no longer complain:

```
if ($targetProcess) {
  $Handle = $targetProcess.MainWindowHandle
  [Void]$User32::SetWindowPos($Handle, -1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0x53)
}
```